# A href"#" data-toggle anchor goes to the top

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

There is a project I took over for restyling and they asked me to fix the anchors for tabs where the user gets send to the top in firefox: http://new.yourcoach.be/opleidingen/nlp-bootcamp/

It works like a charm in Chrome but not in other browsers

```
<script>function changeTab(e){
e.preventDefault();
console.log("Changing tab");
}</script>

 <a class="nav-link <?php if ($i == 1): ?>active<?php endif; ?> text-uppercase"  data-toggle="tab" data-target="#<?php echo sanitize_title($tab['_title']); ?>" href="javascript:;"  onClick="changeTab(event)"><?php echo $tab['_title']; ?> </a>
```

I tried the following without succes:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Anchor</a>

<a href="#" rel="no-refresh">Anchor</a>

<a href="#" onclick="return false;">Anchor</a>

<script>
    $( "tablink" ).click(function() {
        e.preventDefault();
console.log("Changing tab");
    })(jQuery);
</script>
<a id="tablink"  href="#">Anchor</a>
```

**Solution**

```
<a href="#!">Anchor</a>
```

Comment: I am assuming you don’t mean an actual reload, you are just referring to the page jumping to the top?

Comment: Ow yes, I forgot to change it. :)

Comment: With `onClick="changeTab(event)"` you are relying on the existence of the global `event` object, but that is not a given in Firefox. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event

Comment: Do proper jQuery event handler binding here, instead of using “old-school” HTML attributes for this – then you don’t have to deal with stuff like this to begin with.

Comment: `$( "tablink" )` try to find `<tablink>`. Use `$('#tablink')` instead.

Comment: Also, you can remove the `href="#"` from `<a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following worked for all browsers not to go to the top anymore:

```
<a href="#!">Anchor</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To have an html element fire a javascript event, you can either use the `onClick` attribute of the element and enter the javascript function directly in the attribute:

```
# html
<a href="#" onClick="changeTab(event)">Example</a>

# javascript
function changeTab(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // do things
}
```

Or you can just do it in the javascript by hooking onto all elements that match a certain selector. This is the preferred method, as it doesn't mix the html and javascript, which makes it easier to understand what affects what.

```
# html
<a href="#" class="js-change-tab">Example</a>

# javascript
document.querySelectorAll('.js-change-tab').forEach( a => {
    a.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // do things
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a JQuery callback to avoid *event* object issues

```js
<script>
function changeTab(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Changing tab");
}

$(document).on("click", ".nav-link", changeTab);
</script>

 <a class="nav-link <?php if ($i == 1): ?>active<?php endif; ?> text-uppercase"  data-toggle="tab" data-target="#<?php echo sanitize_title($tab['_title']); ?>" href="javascript:;"><?php echo $tab['_title']; ?> </a>
```